# How to require a REFERER for a specific path in apache2 webserver?

Tags: apache, webserver, apache2, http-referer

```
<Location /my-app/files>
    Require all granted
</location>
```

I want to restrict access to `/my-app/files` by using the `%{HTTP_REFERER}`.
Let's for example I want to grant access only for linking by [www.google.de](http://www.google.de) and [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

How could I combine my `Location` with a `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}`?

Comment: Note that this is an optional header, not guaranteed to be present or correct

Comment: I know, and that's fine as I want to create some kind of hotlink restriction feature with it only allowing access from certain domains).